# Deny access to all xml but allowing some files

Tags: xml, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following lines in my .htaccess file:

```
<Files ~ "\.xml$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</Files>
```

However I'd like to allow 3 xml files:

```
green.xml
square.xml
texture.xml
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` rule. Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(green|square|texture)\.xml$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.xml$ - [NC,F]
```

Comment: Applied your code. I got .htaccess and the xml files in the root directory but I still get 'Access Denied' for those xml exceptions :(

Comment: Try this in a different browser? Also you have other rules too?

Comment: Didn't work in an other browser. I have more rules, yes. I found some code that did work, but only for one xml file:     <Files green.xml>
Allow from all
Satisfy all
</Files>  Do you know how to also include square.xml and texture.xml by using this code?

Comment: Did you not comment out your `<Files ~ "\.xml$">` code? My rule was supposed to replace your existing `<Files ~ "\.xml$">` segment. It will be much easier if you post your current .htaccess in question so that I can suggest you final version.

Comment: My bad, it works now that I commented out `<Files ~ "\.xml$">`. Thank you @anubhava !